# Error: LNK1104: cannot open file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker

So I have a really stupid problem. Since recently my anti-virus kept complaining about my program every time I build and ran it, and just now I accidently "removed the threat". Now I keep getting the error LNK1104: cannot open file:'C:\blahblah\Documents\vs2012\Projects\program\Debug\program.exe', in release mode it compiles fine. I've tried removing the debug folder and restarting VS (which sometimes seems to solve linker-errors), but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've configured your virus scanner to remove the compiled executable that the linker emits. And it looks like the virus scanner is doing so every time you regenerate the executable.

The solution is to find the option in your virus scanner to stop it deleting that file.